# FlinkSQL Table Gone after Session Closed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I access to job manager session sqlclient.sh

I wanted to stream the kafka topic via flinksql so i execute the script below to create table, however when I exit the session, the table gone.

```bash
Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE en_trans (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `purchaseId` INTEGER,
>    PRIMARY KEY (ID) NOT ENFORCED
> ) WITH (
>   'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
>   'topic' = 'en_trans',
>   'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-netlex-cp-kafka:9092,....',
>   'properties.group.id' = 'en_group_test',
>   'key.format' = 'avro-confluent',
>   'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
>   'key.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-sg-cp-schema-registry:8081',
>   'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-sg-cp-schema-registry:8081'
> );
```

```sql
Flink SQL> show tables;
+------------+
| table name |
+------------+
|   en_trans |
+------------+
```

After Session shut down

```
Flink SQL>

Shutting down the session...
done.
```

I go to sqlclient again

```
Flink SQL> show tables;

Empty set
```

Where is it goes wrong ??

the flink-conf.yaml as below

```yaml
    jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 1600m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1728m
    state.backend: rocksdb
    state.backend.type: rocksdb
    state.backend.incremental: true
    sql-client.execution.result-mode: tableau
    # sql-client.execution.max-table-result.rows: 10000
    # table.exec.state.ttl: 1000
    execution.runtime-mode: batch
    # state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs:///flink-checkpoints # location to store checkpoints
    # state.savepoints.dir: hdfs:///flink-savepoints
    state.backend.local-recovery: true
    process.taskmanager.working-dir: /pv
    parallelism.default: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The data belonging to the table is still there, it's just the table metadata that hasn't been preserved in a persistent catalog. If you recreate the table, you'll be right back where you were.

Comment: hi @David Anderson, how May I create the persistent catalog? I can't find a complete document that create a persistent catalog. Couldn't be just file based format? (Must required hdfs?)

Comment: The only persistent catalogs that ship with open source Flink are the JDBC and Hive catalogs. There is no file-based catalog implementation, but you could instead use a start-up file with the SQL Client to recreate all of your tables, etc during session initialization. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/#initialize-session-using-sql-files

Comment: I would preferred go for JDBC if it is just for catalog configuration. 
But if i would go for JDBC, where can I configure the SSL connection?  If you don't mind, what are the library is required ? Based on the https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#connector-options , it did not offer SSL connection just like kafka-connect `ssl.mode`, `ssl.rootcertfile`

Comment: I have registered JDBC Catalog, I got error where create table.
`
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
`

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Client creates an in-memory one which will go away when you exit the client's session.

You will need to configure and use a durable catalog such as the JdbcCatalog or HiveCatalog.  You can read more about catalogs here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/catalogs/.

Comment: I don't have Hive/JDBC now. Can I use file instead ? I got this error 

"could not find any factory for identifier 'table-store' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.CatalogFactory' in the classpath"

Comment: Sort of.  

If you put all your DDL commands into a file, you could initialize each SQL client session using it.  That's what David Anderson is suggesting in his comment above.

Comment: Nope, i don't want loading 100++ ddl script whenver start up a session .

@GeoJim, i m having issue when using jdbc catalog

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465698/could-not-execute-createtable-in-path-en-catalog-flinkdb-en-trans-java-lan

Comment: Makes sense.  Folks can help more on that SO question.

Comment: the JDBC Catalog is not yet for persistent, it took me 2 weeks just realized.