# Could not execute CreateTable in path `en_catalog`.`flinkdb`.`en_trans` java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to use JDBCCatalog for durable catalog, but i've gotten error while creating table.

I am just trying to have durable table whenever login to sql client session, it's link to my previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454277/flinksql-table-gone-after-session-closed) which advised by them

```bash
CREATE CATALOG tadika_catalog WITH(
    'type' = 'jdbc',
    'default-database' = 'flinkdb',
    'username' = 'flink',
    'password' = 'flink',
    'base-url' = 'jdbc:mysql://....:3306'
);


Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE en_trans (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `purchaseId` INTEGER
> ) WITH (
>   'connector' = 'kafka',
>   'topic' = 'en_trans',
>   'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-netlex-cp-kafka:9092,....',
>   'properties.group.id' = 'en_group_test',
>   'key.format' = 'avro-confluent',
>   'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
>   'key.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-netlex-cp-schema-registry:8081',
>   'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-netlex-cp-schema-registry:8081'
> );


.....
.....
caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Could not execute CreateTable in path `en_catalog`.`flinkdb`.`en_trans`

...
...
...


[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised jdbc catalog is not yet to persist flink metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The usage pattern is this:

```sql
CREATE CATALOG MyCatalog WITH (...);

USE CATALOG MyCatalog;

CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;

USE MyDatabase;

CREATE TABLE MyTable ...;
```

Comment: It did not work on CREATE Database, the exception shown as below. 

is it the library mismatch ? `flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.1-1.17.jar:3.1.1-1.17`

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.catalog.AbstractJdbcCatalog.createDatabase(AbstractJdbcCatalog.java:209) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.1-1.17.jar:3.1.1-1.17]
 at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.createDatabase(CatalogManager.java:1381) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
 at ....

Comment: I just realized there is no `createDatabase` or `createTable` in mysqlCatalog
https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-jdbc/blob/main/flink-connector-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc/databases/mysql/catalog/MySqlCatalog.java