# Flinksql Create Hive catalog caused "Configured default database default doesn't exist in catalog myhive."

Tags: hive, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have followed the [instruction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/) to install relevant libs and hive depends. However it's still not working when i create catalog. It seemed like the project is not stable yet. I have also try [jdbc catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465698/could-not-execute-createtable-in-path-en-catalog-flinkdb-en-trans-java-lan) and it also not working either

```
CREATE CATALOG myhive WITH (
'type' = 'hive',
'default-database' = 'default',
'hive-conf-dir' = '/opt/hive-conf'
);

Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not execute CREATE CATALOG: (catalogName: [myhive], properties: [{hive-conf-dir=/opt/hive-conf, default-database=default, type=hive}])
at org.apache.flink.table.operations.ddl.CreateCatalogOperation.execute(CreateCatalogOperation.java:75) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1092) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.callOperation(OperationExecutor.java:556) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.executeOperation(OperationExecutor.java:444) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.executeStatement(OperationExecutor.java:207) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.SqlGatewayServiceImpl.lambda$executeStatement$1(SqlGatewayServiceImpl.java:212) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager.lambda$submitOperation$1(OperationManager.java:119) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager$Operation.lambda$run$0(OperationManager.java:258) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.catalog.exceptions.CatalogException: Configured default database default doesn't exist in catalog myhive.
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog.open(HiveCatalog.java:309) ~[flink-connector-hive_2.12-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.createCatalog(CatalogManager.java:309) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.ddl.CreateCatalogOperation.execute(CreateCatalogOperation.java:68) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1092) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.callOperation(OperationExecutor.java:556) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.executeOperation(OperationExecutor.java:444) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.executeStatement(OperationExecutor.java:207) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.SqlGatewayServiceImpl.lambda$executeStatement$1(SqlGatewayServiceImpl.java:212) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager.lambda$submitOperation$1(OperationManager.java:119) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager$Operation.lambda$run$0(OperationManager.java:258) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    ... 1 more

[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.catalog.exceptions.CatalogException: Configured default database default doesn't exist in catalog myhive.
```

And my hive-site.xml below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:postgresql://.....:5432/metastore</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://.....:9083</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>hive</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>org.jpox.autoCreateSchema</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

And i try to access my hive server, it does have the db

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/hive/conf/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive> show databases;
OK
abc
default
Time taken: 1.374 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: you configured `'hive-conf-dir' = '/opt/hive-conf'` but your hive saying that it's using `configuration in file:/opt/hive/conf/`. Probably your path is just pointing to a wrong place ? It happened to me once when I followed instructions but my conf wasin the different location.

Comment: Nope, `/opt/hive/conf` is under hive-docker. This is `/opt/hive-conf` under flink

Comment: there is no hive-conf under the flink (at least there weren't in previous versions). You should use conf of your Hive in Docker I think. Flink will have information about your Hive from this file if you pointing to something different it won't work. I did the same mistake (on Yarn in my case). It worked only when I gave the right path to my hive-conf from Hive not from Flink or copy of yarn-site.xml or anything else.

Comment: I have tried pull the hive-site.xml to mapped with flink. It is still the same. I did connected to hive-docker. I am not sure what was left

Comment: I think the problem in your environment. Flink unable to see docker container with Hive for some reason (is it in docker container too by the way?). Maybe provide more details about your configuration, libraries, dependencies?

Comment: I am not sure how i give you details at here, could we move to chat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. The `HIVE Metastore version` has to be same/relatively with `flink-sql-connector-hive-<HIVE_RELATIVELY_VERSION>_2.12-1.14.6.jar` This is very tedious as Documentation not really well.

Answer (score 0):

This example -- https://github.com/fhueske/flink-sql-demo -- uses out-of-date versions of the components (Flink, Kafka, MySQL, Hive), but it's a working example that should help you get started.